# Getting link from an HTML file

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

I want to take link to a pdf file from HTML file of the website. Preferably using Python 3.

https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2Fb100747

I have to download pdf files from this website, but direct links to files themselves are not available to me. Ihave to go to the page an manually click and download each book from the batch of 408! I want to automatize the process. Where it grabs the HTML of the file, looks up the link for the file and then downloads it. But that proved to be unsuccessful and I am looking for new method.

Comment: Try selenium...

Comment: ...because is does JavaScript.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=selenium+download